# Volume of irregular polyhedron

Tags: integration, volume

Let H denotes a polyhedron with its base being a triangle
PQR with PQ = QR = 1/2 unit and angle Q = 90 degree .
The cover ( upper layer ) of the polyhedron is determined by
the equation : z= 1/2 x - x^2 + 1/2 y - y^2 - xy .
Thus for QR , the x-axis or y= 0 , the equation becomes
z = 1/2 x - x^2 being a quadratic curve over QR ;
for PQ , the y-axis or x = 0 , the equation becomes
z = 1/2 y - y^2 being a quadratic curve over PQ ;
for PR ( represented by x + y = 1/2 ) the equation becomes
z = 1/4 - x^2 - y^2 - xy also being a quadratic curve over PR .
We may find that the above 3 curves all have maximum
values = 1/16 unit at the mid-points of PQ ,QR and PR .
Moreover the polyhedron has an apex at the point with
coordinate ( 1/6 , 1/6 , 1/12 ) .
Find the volume of the polyhedron H . ( looks somewhat
like a tent )

Comment: Hi -- welcome to math.SE! [Here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020)'s a reference and tutorial for typesetting math on this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I take it the sides and bottom are flat but the top looks something like this:
[image]

I think you're just supposed to integrate the height over the triangular base, that is
$$\begin{align}V&=\int_0^{\frac12}\int_0^{\frac12-x}\left[\frac12x-x^2+\frac12y-y^2-xy\right]dy\,dx\\
&=\int_0^{\frac12}\left[\frac12xy-x^2y+\frac14y^2-\frac13y^3-\frac12xy^2\right]_0^{\frac12-x}dx\\
&=\int_0^{\frac12}\left[\frac12x\left(\frac12-x\right)-x^2\left(\frac12-x\right)+\frac14\left(\frac12-x\right)^2-\frac13\left(\frac12-x\right)^3-\frac12x\left(\frac12-x\right)^2\right]dx\\
&=\left[-\frac14x\left(\frac12-x\right)^2-\frac1{12}\left(\frac12-x\right)^3+\frac12x^2\left(\frac12-x\right)^2+\frac13x\left(\frac12-x\right)^3\right.\\
&\left.+\frac1{12}\left(\frac12-x\right)^4-\frac1{12}\left(\frac12-x\right)^3+\frac1{12}\left(\frac12-x\right)^4+\frac16x\left(\frac12-x\right)^3+\frac1{24}\left(\frac12-x\right)^4\right]_0^{\frac12}dx\\
&=0+\frac1{96}+0+0-\frac1{192}+\frac1{96}-\frac1{192}+0-\frac1{384}=\frac1{128}\end{align}$$

Comment: user 5713492 !

Your  diagram  is  exactly  what  I  imagined , and  it  makes  the problem  much  clearer . The  volume  required  I  mean  the  volume  bound  by  the  bottom , the  top  and  the   perpendicular  planes  on  
the  3  sides .
I  got  an  answer  of  1/128 ( being  3  times  of  your  answer  1/384 ) 
from  another  place . How  do  you  comment  that  answer ?

Comment: Yes, you are right, @mrwong! I don't know how I wrote down the diagonal boundary as $y=x$ when even the problem statement said $y=\frac12-x$. The answer of $V=\frac1{128}$ makes a lot more sense in that $(\text{max height})\times(\text{area of base})=\frac1{12}\frac18=\frac1{96}$, which is an upper bound for the volume, is only a little bigger than this. Another way you could see that my original answer was incorrect was that terms like $\frac12x$ and $\frac12y$ should integrate for the same values by symmetry.

Comment: Thanks  @user5713492 , using  your  answer  on  
this  question  , the  answer  of  part  (2)  of  the  
question  I  asked  in  May  25  "  probability ---
intersection  of  triangles  "  can  be  deduced  to  
be  1/2 . Will  you  be  interested  to  solve  other  
parts  of  that  question ?

Comment: I can't post an answer because the question has been put on hold. Your best bet is to write up the answers you have achieved in your question, neatly formatted of course, and perhaps the hold will be removed. I can't go against the wishes of those more experienced on this site, so you are going to have to try and change their opinions.